# Крошится(и не только) сайт в реакт при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Сайт начинает ломаться(не прогружаются картинки, видео, музыка итп. так же на сервер передаются запросы по типу "readprevention/(путь к файлам)) при переходах по таким ссылкам "readprevention/:IDprevention" и необязательно это должна быть динамической, при статичных тоже самое.

```
 const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
    path: "/",
    element:  <App />,
    children: [
    {
    path: "news",
    element: <NewsScreen />,
    },
    {
    path: "prevention",
    element: <PreventionScreen/>,
    },
    {
    path: "attendance/:IDattendance",
    element: <AttendanceScreen />,
    },
    ],
    },
    {
    path: "*",
    element:  <NotFound />,
    },
    ]);  



root.render(  <RouterProvider router={router} /> );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была не маршрутах, а в путях для файлов.
все файлы хранились в папке public и путь для них прописывался ./public/путь до файла
весь проект хранится в папке frontend что является корнем проекта.
__frontend
|
--public
|
-- src

и при переходе глубже /, /home,/about итп он терял связь с файлами.